# Aplicacion cliente-servidor C#, sql server y distribucion

Tags: c#, sql-server

Buenos dias a todos.

Tengo una aplicacion ya terminada que es cliente-servidor, pero ahora quiero distribuirlo a mis clientes y quiero limitarlos.

Por ejemplo quiero hacer un paquete de 5 clientes y el servidor.

Aqui mi preguntas es como puedo limitar a solo 5 clientes o los que yo quiera para distriburilo pero ejemplo paquete 1 de 5 clientes y el servidor o paquete 2 de 10 clientes y el servidor?
porque ahorita la aplicacion se instala y solo apuntando al servidor de base de datos y esta funciona bien, pero no es viable para mi.

O puedo generar una licencia por cada usuario y si es necesario agregar una licencia mas a cada paquete ya seria un cliente extra y se venderia una licencia unica.

Answer (score 1):

La idea sería que generes una licencia por cada cliente, y una licencia para el servidor, esa licencia controlaría el número de clientes que se pueden conectar. De modo que con cada cliente que se conecte, en el servidor vas contando y comparando con tu licencia de servidor.

Answer (score 1):

Va a depender de tipo de licencia que quieras aplicar: por puesto o por concurrencia. Si es por concurrencia lo tienes más sencillo. El cliente puede distribuirse e instalarse libremente, mientras que tu desde el servidor controlas las sesiones abiertas.

Si lo que quieres es licencias nominales (por puesto) en el cliente, crea unos `Guid` en el servidor que serán las claves necesarias para activar en cada instalación. Tu programa cliente, en su primera ejecución deberá pedir esa clave y además crear un `Guid` adicional, que enviará al servidor.

En el servidor tendrás una tabla `licencias` con la lista de licencias (`Guid`) creadas por el servidor, que deberán emparejarse con el `Guid` del cliente generado en la primera ejecución. Si se instala un nuevo cliente con la misma licencia, no lo registrarás debido a que ya está emparejado.

En el servidor deberás tener una gestión de licencias, para añadir, quitar o resetear si fuera necesario.

Esta es una estrategia general que puede mejorarse en los detalles. Pero por mi experiencia es simple y funciona.